# Как можно ограничить авторизацию пользователя только с одного браузера?

Tags: php

Вот самая задача: Сделайте авторизацию по паролю, при условии определенного браузера пользователя. Я знаю, что нужно использовать $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], но он показывает какими браузера пользуется пользователь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можете использовать данную функцию для определения браузера

```
function get_user_browser() {
    $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (strpos($user_agent, 'MSIE') !== false) return 'Internet Explorer';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'OPR') !== false) return 'Opera';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'YaBrowser') !== false) return 'Yandex Browser';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Vivaldi') !== false) return 'Vivaldi';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Maxthon') !== false) return 'Maxthon';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Edge') !== false) return 'Microsoft Edge';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Firefox') !== false) return 'Mozilla Firefox';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Chrome') !== false) return 'Google Chrome';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Safari') !== false) return 'Safari';
    else return 'Unknown';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь)